# Exclude directory from production build with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have some mock data files that I would like to serve in development mode, but exclude from my bundle.

My project structure is:

```
/src/
    index.html
    Router.jsx
    /components
    /mockdata <- I don't need this guy in my bundle.js
```

Is it possible to exclude the `/mockdata` directory from my bundle, but still serve the files via the webpack-dev-server? I'm not seeing anything in the output section of the webpack docs, but I'm hoping there's a workaround.

The files in the `/mockdata` directory are loaded via ajax. My webpack config is broken into two parts:

Development

```
// webpack.config.js

/*eslint-env node*/
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000
  },
  entry: './src/Router.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: "react"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        loader : 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|es6)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src')),
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6']
  }
};
```

and production:

```
// webpack.prod.config.js

var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    }
  })
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
      minChunkSize: 51200, // ~50kb
  })
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: true,
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    },
    output: {
      comments: false
    }
  })
);

config.plugins.push(
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: 'src/static',
      to: 'static'
    },
    {
      from: 'src/index.html'
    }
  ])
);

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: How do you refer to `mockdata` in your code? Any chance for webpack config?

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen They're loaded via ajax. I have added my webpack configs.

Comment: It should not bundle `mockdata` if you aren't pointing to it directly. Hard to say what's going on based on the current information.

Comment: Ah. So basically if I'm not requiring/importing anything from the directory it won't be imported? I was thinking it would wrap up everything in the `/src` directory regardless. If not, awesome :)

Comment: Yeah. If you would like to bundle the `mockdata` for some reason, you would have to explicitly point to it through the asset graph. You can [analyze the build output](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/analyzing-build-statistics/) to get a better idea of what's going on.